# How to make my own compilation error in java ?

Tags: java

how can I enforce the compiler to give me an error if the parameter (String Path) that is sent to the constructor can't be a directory?

```
import java.io.File;
public class Folder {

    protected File file;

    public Folder(String Path){
    file = new File(Path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider adding more detail to your question including more examples of what you've tried.

Comment: I assume your intent is to make a Folder class that can never have a non directory File object. Not that you specifically need to fail at compile time?

Comment: This is the first time that I have seen someone asking how to *create* an error...

Answer (score 2):

You can't make it a compile error (unless you rewrite the compiler of course and even then, I don't think you can determine at compile time if a string is a valid directory).

The standard way to deal with this in java would be to throw an exception, for example:

```
if (isNotValid(path)) { //condition to be defined
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(path + " is not a valid path");
}
```

Comment: I thought that it might be done using annotations

Comment: @A.R.Mansour How do you determine that a path is valid at compile time. For example: `C:/temp` is a valid Windows path but (I think) an invalid linux or osx path.

Comment: by the isDirectory() mehod in the File class
like i want it to make a compilation error when isDirectory() return false

Comment: @A.R.Mansour: something has got you horribly confused. How would the compiler on the *build* computer know *at compilation time* what is a valid directory on the *target* computer *at run time*?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly with some kind of annotation processor.

But it's a pretty strange requirement. What happens if it's a directory at compile time, but it's not a run time?

Comment: I can't understand your question sorry.
what do you mean by "What happens if it's a directory at compile time, but it's not a run time?"

Comment: You wanted a "compiler error" if the parameter doesn't represent a directory. So, when you compile your code, let's say you figure out what value the parameter will have at runtime, and it meets your requirement. What happens later on when you actually run your code (instead of just compiling it) and find that the parameter no longer represents a directory?

Answer (score 0):

*Can't be a directory* in what ? In Windows ? In Linux ?

Java is cross-platforms, and every platform has its own specifications (eg. in Windows you can't use `*` in directory names, but in Linux you can...);

I think you just need to check [isDirectory()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory%28%29) method of File class from inside your method at runtime.

Comment: The OP asked for a compile error, not a runtime error.

Comment: I know, thanks... i suggested a runtime error, leaving the JVM to worry about the validation of the directory in the running platform.

Answer (score 0):

A compile time error won't be possible.

Yet consider this implementation :

```
public class Folder {

    private final File folder;

    public Folder(String path) {
        this(new File(path));
    }

    public Folder(File folder) {
        if (!folder.exists() || !folder.isDirectory()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.folder = folder;
    }

    // add useful methods possibly delegating to contained File object ...
}
```

This effectively prevents making Folder objects that contain a non directory File. Also note that I've set the folder field private, so no other class can tamper with it.

Comment: The OP asked for a compile error, not a runtime error.

Comment: @dty I took that as badly worded, and assumed his intent was to make a Folder class that could never have a non directory File object.

Comment: I suspect you're right, but his wording was quite clear. I'll refund the downvote, and downvote the question and vote to close too.

Comment: Perhaps we should get more info on his intent, and edit his question

Answer (score 0):

You could realize a similar feature by using automatic unit tests, that run on every build.

First, you need to validate the parameter in the `Folder` constructor, so that a `Exception` is thrown, if the path is not valid.

Then you write unit tests, that runs and tests all of your code. If the test fails, the BUILD fails, too - and the whole packaging of the project fails. (eg. the hard-coded directory is not accessible)
This is quite like a compiler error, the build process would fail. (sure it is not the same)

The tests make sure, that the code you tested works in the desired way.

Of course, this is more easy if you are using build tool like maven, where the unit tests run automatically in every build.